# How do I maximize ffmpeg's performance?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to copy the video and convert the audio to EAC3 while dropping the subs, so I'm using this command

> E:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe -y -i "E:\source.mkv" -map 0 -vcodec copy
> -threads 6 -sn -acodec eac3 -b:a 640k -metadata:s:a:0 title="EAC3 5.1" "E:\destination.mkv"

but on my Windows 10 6-core i7 (3.5GHz) it's only outputting an average of 13x, 295 FPS, while CPU utilization is at 15% or below. How can this be improved so I can get closer to 100% CPU utilization?

Comment: Conversion of audio does not lend itself to using multiple cores.

Comment: Run multiple instances of ffmpeg if you have more than 1 file to convert.

Comment: Using multiple instances to convert multiple files' audio only further degrades performance

Comment: Does converting audio of N files degrade performance by more than 1/N ?

Comment: It's hard to tell actually because reading the HDD is a bottleneck. I've been reading from a HDD and writing to an SSD and the HDD is at 85% with 2 files and maxes out at 3 files. Nonetheless, the CPU uses two cores only, regardless of the number of files it processes at the same time.